# Setup Tailwind with Blazor in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css, blazor-webassembly, tailwind-3

I've created a new Blazor WASM project,I removed bootstrap files(also from index.html) then I've setup Tailwind:

```
 npm init -y
 npm install -D tailwindcss
 npx tailwindcss init
```

added  `content: ["./**/*.{razor,html}"]`  in tailwind.config.js

created  styles/app.css:

```
 @tailwind base;
 @tailwind components;
 @tailwind utilities;
```

in package.json, added:

```
   "scripts": {
      "css:build": "tailwindcss -i ./styles/app.css -o ./wwwroot/css/app.css",
      .. 
     }
```

in BlazorApp3.csproj:

```
 <Target Name="Tailwind" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="npm run css:build"/>
    </Target>
```

css file is created only when I start my project,after any modification app is reloaded but css is not rebuild

thanks

Comment: Does work any kind of tailwind inteli sense?

Comment: what happens if you run the following from the command line?


`npx tailwindcss -i ./styles/app.css -o ./wwwroot/css/app.css --watch --minify`

Comment: if I run external command manually it works but I want something integrated into project

Comment: Are you building the project on your local machine or on a CI server?

running this command will build your project and you should  get the css:build step output in your terminal window or in the CI server logs.

`dotnet build .\<your-solution-name>.sln`

Comment: A thought as you mentioned that the css is not rebuilt and integrated into the project.  Is this because you are developing the app?

It could be you are missing a binding before build in your package.json file 

`"-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [ "css:build" ]

  }`

This will run the css build each time you press F5

Comment: not working for me.I'm runnig local project with VS 2022.can you post a working empty template?